# Use pseudo classes for selecting webkit pseudo elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, pseudo-element, shadow-dom

Not sure if the title is really clear.

What I try to do is to select a webkit pseudo element (inside shadow dom) with a `:nth-of-type` pseudo class.

So I want to select the second `-webkit-datetime-edit-text` pseudo element in an `input`.

[image]

I thought that I could do it like this:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text:nth-of-type(2){
  display: none;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

ps: For those who aren't aware of the possibility to inspect the shadow dom see [here point nr 12](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/03/15-must-know-chrome-devtools-tips-tricks/).

Comment: psuedo="" ?? is this a valid html?

Comment: @MRLister  this is the shadow dom content of a default html input type time

Comment: It would really help us if you pasted your actual html rather than a picture of it

Comment: @Pete here you go :-)  https://fiddle.jshell.net/82s1wy6v/

Comment: A [better fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0zh6aaj5/1/) to show the ones that don't know chrome shadow styling that it works when directly accessing shadow elements, by their `pseudo` attribute. Of course to be run in chrome, with the *Show user agent shadow DOM*  option triggered in the dev-tools. cc @MrLister

Comment: @MrLister http://tutorialzine.com/2015/03/15-must-know-chrome-devtools-tips-tricks/ see visualize shadow dom

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa just tried your solution, doesn't work either

Comment: @OlivierKrull - Yes just figured, it would not because what you are trying to edit is the browser generated shadow DOM and cannot be altered. You can use any of the methods shown ONLY if you create a shadow DOM using `createShadowRoot()` (javascript method) i believe. Always remember the shadow root must say `#shadow-root (open)` and NOT `#shadow-root (user-agent)`

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa: Why'd you suggest `#host::shadow div:nth-of-type(2)[pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-text"]` then, if you know that the UA default shadow trees cannot be altered?

Comment: @BoltClock - I researched a lot myself now and figured out the issue ... already deleted that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's complete hack time !!!

<sub>For a real solution, pass your way. But anyway playing with vendor-specific pseudo-element means you're open to hacks, aren't you ?</sub>

There unfortunately doesn't seem to be any way to combine pseudo-selectors on pseudo-elements.
But while trying out some things and others, I ended up with this awful hack :

The element before this second `:` can be targeted. So we can place on top of the real target, with an white background, and pretend that this `:` doesn't exist.

```css
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field {
    background: white;
    z-index: 4;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<input type=time step="1" value="00:00:00">
```