# Webkit Pseudo Elements Documentation

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I actually acomplished what I wanted to do: hiding some webkit pseudo-elements from the page when I want to print it, the code looks like below.

The problem is that I didnt learn anything from my research to do tha and I couldn't find any documentation about it, and every answer I saw about this topic only shows the code, without any further explanation.

```
::-webkit-resizer,
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none; 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

[image]

Some sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions

  - This one show some extensions, but the callendar one is not listed here and I wasn't able to find elsewhere.
- https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334

  - This gist has a lot of those pseudo elements, classes or properties, but the guy who did it didnt explain how he have acomplished that, and those doenst show on my dev tools.
- [Use pseudo classes for selecting webkit pseudo elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846163/use-pseudo-classes-for-selecting-webkit-pseudo-elements)

  - This guy talks about the shadow-dom, I didnt heard of it before, but on my research I couldn't understand how it would help-me.

Some similar answers: 6195329, 11418289, 17340038, 15530850, 53483852

Also visited the wikipedia article and this site: https://webkit.org/

I really want to understand the concept behind this webkit things and any help would be appeciated.

To be more specific: if any time in the future I want to override a component, how can I know what pseudo-element has being aplied on an compnonet given the browser?

Comment: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/

Comment: @zer00ne On my research I passed by this article, it unfortunately doesnt have all pseudo-elements neither the the way to find them, but it sure is a good article! Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382108/hide-form-controls-when-printing-an-html-page-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific documentation for pseudo-elements, but I finally could find, while tinkering on the Chrome Dev Tools' preferences a setting that shows the "Shadow-Dom" from the user-agent.

Go to "Preferences" and scroll to the "Elements" section, where there is a oprtion for that:

[image: shadow-dom option for google chrome]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know which pseudo-elements you can work with is by reading specifications (like [W3C standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/)) and realiable docs and resources (like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)). If you can't find a particular pseudo-element there (or if it's only referred with a [vendor prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)), you should probably avoid using it.

It seems `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` is supported by [Blink](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator&sq=&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc:third_party%2Fblink%2F) and [WebKit](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls) (follow the links for little pieces of information), but since it's poorly documented and also non-standard I would refrain from adopting it at all.